# Javascript public members inaccessible

Tags: javascript, object, member

I have a pretty easy structure:

```
var FORMS = [];

function FormObject(type)
{
    this.FormId = FORMS.length;
    //alert(this.FormId); returns results 0 and 1 respectively.
    this.Type = type;
    FORMS.push(FormObject); 
    this.generate = generate();
}

function generate()
{
    return 5;
}
```

Then I do something like this:

```
var new_form = new FormObject('fruit');
var another  = new FormObject('vegetable');
alert(another.FormId);//as expected, I get 1 as a result
```

And then finally try do something like this:

```
alert(FORMS.length);//result is 2 so I assume the objects got created successfully
alert(FORMS[0]);//prints the whole code of the constructor into the dialog box
```

However when I try something like this:

```
alert(FORMS[0].FormId);//result is undefined!!!
alert(FORMS[0].generate());//it shows an error that the object does not have such method
```

**Why is it undefined?** I tried reading http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html and it says:

```
Patterns

Public

function Constructor(...) {
    this.membername = value;
}
Constructor.prototype.membername = value;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace:

```
FORMS.push(FormObject);
```

with

```
FORMS.push(this);
```

When you push the `FormObject` object, you are pushing the constructor function, not the instance.

Comment: and `this.generate = generate();` with `this.generate = generate;` probably.

Comment: Ouch! Now I'm all blushing :)) Silly me got a lesson again! Thanks so much, David!

Comment: @Yoshi `this.generate = generate;` works for me too. I already tried accessing generate with `alert(another.generate());` and it was ok. Thanks :)